# xarray equivalent of pandas `qcut()` function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-xarray

I want to calculate the [Decile Index](https://github.com/royalosyin/Calculate-Precipitation-based-Agricultural-Drought-Indices-with-Python/blob/master/) - see the `ex1-Calculate Decile Index (DI) with Python.ipynb`.

The `pandas` implementation is simple enough but I need help with applying the bin labels to a new `variable` / `coordinate` using the `groupby_bins()` functionality.

## working example (test dataset)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2011-12-31',freq='M')
lat = np.linspace(-5.175003, -4.7250023, 10)
lon = np.linspace(33.524994, 33.97499, 10)
precip = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(len(time), len(lat), len(lon)))

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {'precip': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], precip)},
    coords={
        'lon': lon,
        'lat': lat,
        'time': time,
    }
)
```

This looks like:

```
Out[]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 10, lon: 10, time: 24)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 33.52 33.57 33.62 33.67 ... 33.82 33.87 33.92 33.97
  * lat      (lat) float64 -5.175 -5.125 -5.075 -5.025 ... -4.825 -4.775 -4.725
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-31 2010-02-28 ... 2011-12-31
Data variables:
    precip   (time, lat, lon) float64 0.1638 -1.031 0.2087 ... -0.1147 -0.6863
```

Calculating the cumulative frequency distribution (normalised rank)

```py
# calculate a cumsum over some window size
rolling_window = 3
ds_window = (
    ds.rolling(time=rolling_window, center=True)
    .sum()
    .dropna(dim='time', how='all')
)
# construct a cumulative frequency distribution ranking the precip values
# per month
def rank_norm(ds, dim='time'):
    return (ds.rank(dim=dim) - 1) / (ds.sizes[dim] - 1) * 100

result = ds_window.groupby('time.month').apply(rank_norm, args=('time',))
result = result.rename({variable:'rank_norm'}).drop('month')

Out[]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (lat: 10, lon: 10, time: 108)
Coordinates:
  * lat        (lat) float64 -5.175 -5.125 -5.075 ... -4.825 -4.775 -4.725
  * lon        (lon) float64 33.52 33.57 33.62 33.67 ... 33.82 33.87 33.92 33.97
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-31 2010-02-28 ... 2018-12-31
Data variables:
    rank_norm  (time, lat, lon) float64 75.0 75.0 12.5 100.0 ... 87.5 0.0 25.0
```

## Pandas Solution

I want to create a variable which will create a new `variable` or `coordinate`
in `ds` that will have the the integers corresponding to the bins from the `bins = [20., 40., 60., 80., np.Inf]`.

Trying to do it in Pandas is relatively simple with the `.qcut` functionality.

```py
test = result.to_dataframe()
bins = pd.qcut(test['rank_norm'], 5, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
result = bins.to_xarray().to_dataset().rename({'rank_norm': 'rank_bins'})

Out[]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (lat: 10, lon: 10, time: 108)
Coordinates:
  * lat       (lat) float64 -5.175 -5.125 -5.075 -5.025 ... -4.825 -4.775 -4.725
  * lon       (lon) float64 33.52 33.57 33.62 33.67 ... 33.82 33.87 33.92 33.97
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-31 2010-02-28 ... 2018-12-31
Data variables:
    rank_bins  (lat, lon, time) int64 4 4 1 4 3 4 5 1 1 2 ... 2 1 1 4 2 4 3 1 2 2
```

## My `xarray` attempt

```py
# assign bins to variable xarray
bins = [20., 40., 60., 80., np.Inf]
decile_index_gpby = rank_norm.groupby_bins('rank_norm', bins=bins)
out = decile_index_gpby.assign()  # assign_coords()
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-8d48b9fc1d56> in <module>
      1 bins = [20., 40., 60., 80., np.Inf]
      2 decile_index_gpby = rank_norm.groupby_bins('rank_norm', bins=bins)
----> 3 out = decile_index_gpby.assign()  # assign_coords()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
    772         Dataset.assign
    773         """
--> 774         return self.apply(lambda ds: ds.assign(**kwargs))
    775
    776

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in apply(self, func, args, **kwargs)
    684         kwargs.pop('shortcut', None)  # ignore shortcut if set (for now)
    685         applied = (func(ds, *args, **kwargs) for ds in self._iter_grouped())
--> 686         return self._combine(applied)
    687
    688     def _combine(self, applied):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in _combine(self, applied)
    691         coord, dim, positions = self._infer_concat_args(applied_example)
    692         combined = concat(applied, dim)
--> 693         combined = _maybe_reorder(combined, dim, positions)
    694         if coord is not None:
    695             combined[coord.name] = coord

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in _maybe_reorder(xarray_obj, dim, positions)
    468
    469 def _maybe_reorder(xarray_obj, dim, positions):
--> 470     order = _inverse_permutation_indices(positions)
    471
    472     if order is None:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in _inverse_permutation_indices(positions)
    110         positions = [np.arange(sl.start, sl.stop, sl.step) for sl in positions]
    111
--> 112     indices = nputils.inverse_permutation(np.concatenate(positions))
    113     return indices
    114

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/nputils.py in inverse_permutation(indices)
     58     # use intp instead of int64 because of windows :(
     59     inverse_permutation = np.empty(len(indices), dtype=np.intp)
---> 60     inverse_permutation[indices] = np.arange(len(indices), dtype=np.intp)
     61     return inverse_permutation
     62

IndexError: index 1304 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `pandas.qcut` is giving you exactly what you expect; e.g. see the bins it returns in your example:

```py
>>> test = result.to_dataframe()
>>> binned, bins = pd.qcut(test['rank_norm'], 5, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], retbins=True)

>>> bins
array([  0. ,  12.5,  37.5,  62.5,  87.5, 100. ])
```

If I understand correctly, you are looking to assign an integer value at each point based on the bin the point falls into.  That is:

- `0.0 <= x < 20.0`: 1
- `20.0 <= x < 40.0`: 2
- `40.0 <= x < 60.0`:  3
- `60.0 <= x < 80.0`: 4
- `80.0 <= x`: 5

For this task I would probably recommend using [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) applied via [`xarray.apply_ufunc`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html):

```py
>>> bins = [0., 20., 40., 60., 80., np.inf]
>>> result = xr.apply_ufunc(np.digitize, result, kwargs={'bins': bins})
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! The only issue i am having is that with this code I am getting 6 bins (the integers are labelled 1-6) but there should only be 5 integers right?

Comment: Hmm...that's sort of surprising.  It seems to work as I described above when I tested it.  Are you using `[0., 20., 40., 60., 80., np.inf]` as your `bins`?

Comment: Yes absolutely the same - I get 5 if I use `bins = [0.0, 20., 40., 60., 80.]`

Comment: If I understand the behavior of `digitize` correctly, I *think* those sets of bins should be theoretically equivalent.  When you have a finite upper bound for your last bin, if a value falls above it, `digitize` will fill it with the integer that is one more than the number of bins.  Can you give an example in your case of a value that is labeled with `6` in the case where `np.inf` is used as the last bin bound?  I feel like there *should* only be 5 bins in that case: [0, 20), [20, 40), [40, 60), [60, 80), and [80, inf).

Comment: Ultimately though, this is mostly for my understanding of what's going on; it seems you have a reasonable working solution now :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you use a `scalar` to define your `bins` then it will only generate 4 ranges. You can check this by looking at the `length` and the name of the `keys` of the `groups` of the resulting *GroupBy* object:

```
mybins = [20., 40., 60., 80., np.inf]

decile_index_gpby = rank_norm.groupby_bins('rank_norm', bins=mybins)

len(decile_index_gpby.groups)
=> 4

decile_index_gpby.groups.keys()
=> [Interval(80.0, inf, closed='right'),
    Interval(20.0, 40.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(60.0, 80.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(40.0, 60.0, closed='right')]
```

To prevent the loss of 1/5th of the values, you would have to change your definition of `mybins` to something like:

```
mybins = [np.NINF, 20., 40., 60., np.inf]
```

which is not what you want.

So use `bins=5` instead:

```
decile_index_gpby = rank_norm.groupby_bins('rank_norm', bins=5)

len(decile_index_gpby.groups)
=> 5

decile_index_gpby.groups.keys()
=> [Interval(80.0, 100.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(20.0, 40.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(60.0, 80.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(40.0, 60.0, closed='right'),
    Interval(-0.1, 20.0, closed='right')]
```