# apply function over all months xarray python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

## Efficiently apply a function over the month of interest xarray

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

time = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2018-12-31',freq='M')
lat = np.linspace(-5.175003, -4.7250023, 10)
lon = np.linspace(33.524994, 33.97499, 10)
precip = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(len(time), len(lat), len(lon)))

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {'precip': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], precip)},
    coords={
        'lon': lon,
        'lat': lat,
        'time': time,
    }
)

Out[]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 10, lon: 10, time: 108)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 33.52 33.57 33.62 33.67 ... 33.82 33.87 33.92 33.97
  * lat      (lat) float64 -5.175 -5.125 -5.075 -5.025 ... -4.825 -4.775 -4.725
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-31 2010-02-28 ... 2018-12-31
Data variables:
    precip   (time, lat, lon) float64 -0.7862 -0.28 1.236 ... 0.6622 -0.7682
```

## My current approach

I currently apply a function by:

- looping through all of the months
- selecting all timesteps in the original dataset with that month
- apply a function to those months (here the normalised rank)
- re-combine the list of monthly `DataArray`s into a `Dataset` with all timesteps

The function might be a difference from climatology, but here it is the normalised rank.
- get the rank of the variable value compared to all other values for that `month` in the dataset
- set it on a range from `0-100`

```py
variable = 'precip'
rank_norm_list = []

# loop through all the months
for mth in range(1, 13):
    # select that month
    ds_mth = (
        ds
        .where(ds['time.month'] == mth)
        .dropna(dim='time', how='all')
    )
    # apply the function to that month (here a normalised rank (0-100))
    rank_norm_mth = (
        (ds_mth.rank(dim='time') - 1) / (ds_mth.time.size - 1.0) * 100.0
    )
    rank_norm_mth = rank_norm_mth.rename({variable: 'rank_norm'})
    rank_norm_list.append(rank_norm_mth)

# after the loop re-combine the DataArrays
rank_norm = xr.merge(rank_norm_list).sortby('time')

Out[]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (lat: 10, lon: 10, time: 108)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-31 2010-02-28 ... 2018-12-31
  * lat        (lat) float64 -5.175 -5.125 -5.075 ... -4.825 -4.775 -4.725
  * lon        (lon) float64 33.52 33.57 33.62 33.67 ... 33.82 33.87 33.92 33.97
Data variables:
    rank_norm  (time, lat, lon) float64 75.0 75.0 12.5 100.0 ... 87.5 0.0 25.0
```

Is there a clever/more efficient way that doesn't involve looping and selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the nice example.  There is indeed a simpler way of doing this using [`groupby` and `apply`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.groupby.DatasetGroupBy.apply.html#xarray.core.groupby.DatasetGroupBy.apply):

```py
def rank_norm(ds, dim):
    return (ds.rank(dim=dim) - 1) / (ds.sizes[dim] - 1.0) * 100.0

result = ds.groupby('time.month').apply(rank_norm, args=('time',))
```

Comment: thanks @spencerkclark! that's really helpful. In a shameless cry for help do you know how to assign bin labels from the groups (i.e. the deciles). The SO question I asked is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485160/assign-values-from-xr-groupby-bins-xarray-python)

Comment: Sure thing!  I gave it a shot; let me know if I'm on the right track there.  I'm happy to amend the answer if needed.